# Team Foundation Server 2013 GitUpgradeTemplate.xaml not found

Tags: git, xaml, tfs, build

I created a new build definition for my project in Team Foundation Server 2013. But as soon as I queue a new build, I get an error that the GitUpgradeTemplate.xaml was not found (Error Code 404). The original error message is in German, so I translated it for you guys. Do you got any ideas how to solve this problem?

German:

```
Ausnahmemeldung: Fehler beim Herunterladen von Datei     
"#/4/BuildProcessTemplates/GitTemplate/GitUpgradeTemplate.xaml". Details
404:Not Found - {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Der 
Container 4 wurde nicht     
gefunden.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileContainer.ContainrNotFoundException,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","typeKey":"ContainerNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":4700} (Typ FileNotFoundException)

Ausnahmestapelüberwachung: bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFileAsString(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath)
 bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.ProcessTemplate.Download(String sourceGetVersion)
bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)
```

My translation:

```
Exception handling: error on downloading the file "#/4/BuildProcessTemplates/GitTemplate/GitUpgradeTemplate.xaml". 
Details 404:Not Found - 
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The container 4 was not found.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileContainer.ContainerNotFoundException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","typeKey":"ContainerNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":4700} (Typ FileNotFoundException)

Exception stack monitoring: at  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFileAsString(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.ProcessTemplate.Download(String sourceGetVersion)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be note that the GitUpgradeTemplate.xaml build process file is available in a git team project.

Secondly, open the build definition file, be sure that the GitUpgradeTemplate.xaml file is available in the Build process file dropdown list.

[image]

Comment: The dropdown list shown in your screenshot has two entries. DefaultTemplate (GitTemplate.12.xaml) and Upgrade Template (GitUpgradeTemplate.xaml). If I selected one of them and click on the download link below the list, I get an alert window with the same error message as in the original post. Only the name of the missing file changes.

I didn't customize the templates, the list used to be like that since I started to work on this issue.